# How to get notification when insert new value in db?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi i  am inserting value in data base in php  i want that when i insert value  in database then my div color should be change

**insert.php**

```
include('conn.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$id=2;

//$sql="insert into messages (message,number,service) values ('dd',".$urlstring.",'ds')";

$sql = 'INSERT INTO messages '.
       '(message,number,service) '.
       'VALUES ( "'.$message.'", "'.$urlstring.'", "'.$service.'" )';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo ("Records  affcted: ". mysql_affected_rows());
//echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="div1" style="height=200px;width=300px;">
</div>
```

here    i want when insert.php execute then  div section should change color  in another file

How can i achieve this

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you inserting the new record using ajax? Or is the page reloading?

Comment: i am inserting ajax without ajax

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
include('conn.php');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$id=2;

//$sql="insert into messages (message,number,service) values ('dd',".$urlstring.",'ds')";

$sql = 'INSERT INTO messages '.
       '(message,number,service) '.
       'VALUES ( "'.$message.'", "'.$urlstring.'", "'.$service.'" )';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo ("Records  affcted: ". mysql_affected_rows());
//echo "Entered data successfully\n";
?>
<style>
#div1{
backgroud-color="yourcolor";
}
</style>
<?php
mysql_close($conn);
```

ah i see.

maybe this can help you: http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/?

Comment: but div is in another file

Answer (score 0):

You can use timer on javascript and create a ajax function to retrieve all inserted data on the database.